# how to set the parameters in dictionary values

Tags: iphone

I am saving the data in external class file but am getting error while saving the Bool value
    as a parameter.
    Below is the source code
    .savefile.h

```
-(void) saveDecreasedActivity:(NSInteger) bathing
                meal:(NSInteger) meal withTitle:(NSString *)title independentItem:(BOOL)timeItem;

        {
            NSMutableDictionary *lDataObj = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

           [lDataDict setValue:lSeqCounter forKey:@"seqCounter"];

            [lDataObj setValue:timeItem forKey:@"independentItem"]; 
        }
```

and i have save the data in other class

```
 [saver saveDecreasedActivity:[self.bathingControl selectedSegmentIndex]
                              meal:[self.mealControl selectedSegmentIndex] withTitle:lTitle independentItem:YES];
```

It was showing

```
timeItem is incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending "BOOL" (aka singned char) to parameter of type id
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't store raw types (integers, booleans, etc) in an `NSDcitionary`, which is a collection of key-value pairs ([see docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

In your case, you can use:

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool: timeItem];
```

in:

```
[lDataObj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: timeItem] forKey:@"independentItem"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only store objects in dictionaries, and BOOL is a type, so you have to wrap it like this:

```
[dictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:aBool] forKey:@"yourKey"];
```

and retrieve it like this:

```
BOOL aBool = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"yourKey"] boolValue];
```

Check the NSNumber class reference for more info.